# Add a new column in a dataframe from another dataframe using category column and then finding max for each category

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (DF2, subset of DF1) with category column and count in each category. This was created from an original dataframe (DF1) which has date, and 7 float columns. Using one of the columns, this category column was created (continous to categorical data). Now for each of these categories, I need to find the max value from each of the remaining 6 columns and add new columns in DF2.

Comment: Can you share more details on your data? Or the attempt you did to solve this?

Comment: You **must** provide a minimal, reproducible example (input + matching output)